# ASP.Net 5 - Dependency issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am having a great deal of issues with ASP.Net 5, and I am having one that has been occurring since I have upgraded my project to Beta5.  The error is the following:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File
>   Error   CS0433  The type 'IHostingEnvironment' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'   Uniti.Api.DNX 4.5.1 D:\Alex\Projects\Uniti\src\Uniti.Api\Startup.cs

I have no clue how to resolve this error, and I am looking for some help solving it.  For reference, my project.json file is located at https://gist.github.com/mw2nukeboy/a65d3acb55f3c7799f6e

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuthBearer": "1.0.0-beta5"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: change your EntityFramework references also from beta4 to beta5

Comment: Which NuGet feed do I have to add for that package?  I can only get up to Beta4

Comment: your global.json must contain     "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta5"

Comment: see [msdn asp-net-5-beta5-now-available.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/06/30/asp-net-5-beta5-now-available.aspx), and [github release notes](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta5)